# I'm making a note app and the NotesView clears all other notes and replaces it with my most recent note

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the NotesView:

```
import 'package:app_two/lib/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/enums/menu_action.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:app_two/lib/services/auth/crud/notes_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {
  late Future _myFuture;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _myFuture = getGet();
  }

  // @override //delete
  // void dispose() {
  //   _notesService.close();
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  getGet() async {
    return await _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Your Notes'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(newNoteRoute);
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
            onSelected: (value) async {
              switch (value) {
                case MenuAction.logout:
                  final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                  if (shouldLogout) {
                    await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      loginRoute,
                      (_) => false,
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return const [
                PopupMenuItem<MenuAction>(
                  value: MenuAction.logout,
                  child: Text('Logout'),
                ),
              ];
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _myFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _notesService.allNotes,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final allNotes = snapshot.data as List<DatabaseNote>;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: allNotes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final note = allNotes[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                note.text,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                softWrap: true,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    default:
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> showLogOutDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Sign out'),
          content: const Text('Are you sure you want to sign out?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                },
                child: const Text('Cancel')),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
                child: const Text('Logout'))
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => value ?? false);
  }
}


//Notes_service

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'crud_exceptions.dart';

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  List<DatabaseNote> _notes = [];

  static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
  NotesService._sharedInstance() {
    _notesStreamController = StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>>.broadcast(
      onListen: () {
        _notesStreamController.sink.add(_notes);
        //populate stream with a stream of notes that we've already read from the database
      },
    );
  }
  factory NotesService() => _shared; //singleton

  late final StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>> _notesStreamController;

  Stream<List<DatabaseNote>> get allNotes => _notesStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser?> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } on DatabaseIsNotOpen {
      open();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNote note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    //make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);
    //update db
    final updatesCount = await db.update(noteTable, {
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedwithCloudColumn: 0,
    });
    if (updatesCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNote>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(noteTable);

    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNote.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> getNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(
      noteTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNote();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNote.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final numberOfdeletions = await db.delete(noteTable);
    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    return numberOfdeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      noteTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    //Make sure owner exists in database withthe correct id
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    }

    const text = '';
    //create the note
    final noteId = await db.insert(noteTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedwithCloudColumn: 1,
    });

    final note = DatabaseNote(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExists();
    }
    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
    });

    return DatabaseUser(id: userId, email: email);
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseorThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      try {
        await open();
      } on DatabaseIsNotOpen {
        open();
      }
      // throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      try {
        await open();
      } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
        //empty
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
    }
    try {
      await _ensureDbIsOpen();
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;
      //create user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);
      //create note table
      await db.execute(createNoteTable);
      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentDirectory();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;

  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });
  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email= $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNote {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

  DatabaseNote({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });

  DatabaseNote.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud =
            (map[isSyncedwithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, text = $text';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNote other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'notes.db';
const noteTable = 'note';
const userTable = 'user';
const idColumn = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const textColumn = 'text';
const isSyncedwithCloudColumn = 'is_synced_with_cloud';
const createUserTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "email" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
        );''';
const createNoteTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "note" (
          "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "text"    TEXT,
          "is_synced_with_cloud"    INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
          FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id"),
          PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
        );''';
```

I'm making a note app and the NotesView clears all other notes and replaces it with my most recent not. I have no idea why this is happening

Each note you input should display on a tile. But instead this happens:[image: All previous notes have been replaced with the most recent one]
But only after I restart the app. In the next images, I add a new note and then restart the application

[image: I add a new note,]
[image: And when I restart the app or hot restart, it replaces everything just like before]

I believe I did something very in my StreamBuilder but don't know what.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `case ConnectionState.active` to `case ConnectionState.done` in your `StreamBuilder`.

Duplication may be occurring due to building your list inside `case ConnectionState.active`.

Comment: Now I just keep getting the circular progress indicator. Does this mean there's another problem with my Notes service maybe?

Comment: If your stream does not close even after sending all the data, that will happen. Make sure that you close your stream after sending all the data.

Comment: It says the snapshot has no data and that's why it isn't rendering the notes. Is there a way to fix this? (Thanks for your response btw).

Comment: Can you post the _notesService code?

Comment: Okay I just did

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your db.update does or your SQL query looks like but if you don't pass the id how are you supposed to update the note?

```
Future<DatabaseNote> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNote note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseorThrow();
    //make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);
    //update db
    final updatesCount = await db.update(noteTable, { ///how does magically know what note to update?
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedwithCloudColumn: 0,
    });
    if (updatesCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }
```

If you're using INSERT OR REPLACE INTO because you don't pass the id you're creating a new row instead of updating it and your cache list is giving you false information because at the end you think you update it correctly and just replace the note with the same id, your cache list doesn't reflect the real information anymore.

If you're updating all notes in your table because the where clause doesn't have an id you will present your current problem when restarting

Check your db layer apart to see if you're actually doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your db.update call so it has a where clause specifying the note id:

db.update(
notesTable,
{textColumn: text},
where: 'id = ?',
whereArgs: [note.id],
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).